# Draw a 3D surface function with plotly (RStudio)

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, curve, surface

I'm working with and I was wondering if a could draw a surface function f(x,y)=z in RStudio. actually, i'd like to plot a plane. Right now, what I'm plotting is this:

```
fit3 <- lm(y1~x1+ealax2,data = datos2)

# Outer part ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
x <- (0:250)/250
y <- (0:250)*100
beta <- fit3$coefficients
fxy <- function(x,y){
  beta[1] + beta[2]*x + beta[3]*y
}
z <- outer(X = x,Y = y,FUN = fxy)
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

plot_ly(x=x,y=y,z = t(z), type = "surface") %>% 
  add_trace(data = datos2, x = ~x1, y = ~ealax2, z = ~y1,
            mode = "markers", type = "scatter3d", 
            marker = list(size = 5, color = "red"))
```

And I'm getting this:

[image: surface with scatterplot]

What I want is not to do the "outer" part, which is:

```
x <- (0:250)/250
y <- (0:250)*100
beta <- fit3$coefficients
fxy <- function(x,y){
  beta[1] + beta[2]*x + beta[3]*y
}
z <- outer(X = x,Y = y,FUN = fxy)
```

So the things would be easier. I mean, there are easier ways to plot y=f(x) functions in R such as:

```
curve(cos(x),from=-2,to=5)
```

And I'm looking for something like this but in plotly and moreover with 3D plots. Is there any way to do this or at last a 2D version?

You will be able to download my data from this site: [datos2.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CSX3H8OAdObFaxM2EzzcWlwpRizuMjG6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I guessing you want to plot a "plane". Do you know the function for a plane? Do you know how to write a function in R? Have you done any searching? (I found several examples of 3d surfaces plotted with plotly by way of R using SO's search engine.)

Comment: well im actually doing a lineal regression and i'd like to trace a plane for the scatterplot of the response variable v.s. the covariables

Comment: Great. Show us some code and data. And show what difficulty you are having when you try to apply the examples you can find with searching.

Comment: you can find my data here: [datos2.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CSX3H8OAdObFaxM2EzzcWlwpRizuMjG6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to explain what is meant by the "outer part".

Comment: There it is, I hope I can let me understand that way. Thanks for your support!